# .htaccess rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know not my .htaccess is working since it is showing the ErrorDocument 404 when it can't locate a file.

I am trying to re-write the url so that domain.com/products/123 will become domain.com?product.php?productid=123

This is my .htaccess and it is not doing the trick. When I write domain.com/products/123 in the browser, I get the ErrorDocument 404.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/products/([0-9]+)/$ product.php?productid=$1

ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the product.php in the root folder?

Comment: sorry forgot to comment on that. Yes the product.php is in the root.

Comment: try to delete the / before products/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem after a while.

This was the bugged code:
    RewriteRule ^/products/([0-9]+)/$ product.php?productid=$1

Abadon was right about the / before products, but also there should be ? before the $. So this code will work like it should:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ product.php?productid=$1
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

mhh i think it is the / before products... try if it is working if you delete it

Comment: it still doesn't work. The weird thing is, that with or without the / before products I get "/products/123" on the Error 404 page when I use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']